# Animate removal of list items

Tags: xaml, animation, winrt-xaml, itemscontrol, win-universal-app

I created an `ItemsControl` element in my XAML page. I added an animation when the new items are being added through the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="ItemsControl" x:Key="NotificationsList">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="-40" FromVerticalOffset="0" />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is great; the items slide in from the left as they get added.

Now, I need to add an animation for removal of items. I have two challenges:

1. How to apply an animation on an item when the object is removed from the bound `ObservableCollection`? For example, something like *ExitingThemeTransition*.
2. The items that get removed are always from the bottom of the `ItemsControl`. This causes the remaining items to just drop down by the height of the removed items, which seems to be difficult to follow. How do I make the animation that would gracefully move down the remaining items? Is that possible?

I am using Universal Windows Apps API (Windows 10 / WinRT). Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `AddDeleteThemeTransition`?

Comment: @JustinXL I did, bu the animation looks quite weird when the items are removed. First, the entire list collapses by the height of the removed item (as described in the second number in the question), and then suddenly the removed item appears below the list bottom and then it gets animated by a fade out (as `AddDeleteThemeTransition` implies).